# How to insert QChartView in form with Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, qchart, qchartview

I want to add `QChart` to the form. But I can't find it in the Widget Box. So I created it in the code. How can I insert it in `QWidget` or `QFrame` or something else?

I want to set area of that widget in QtDesigner.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Option 1: Promoted

I suppose you mean inserting a QChartView, because QChartView inherits from QGraphicsView, this would be a good option, for this we do the following:

1. first add `QT += charts` in the .pro
2. place the QGraphicsView to the design.
3. Right click on the QGraphicsView and select `Promote to...`
4. When doing the above, a menu appears, in the menu it should be set in `QChartView` in `Promoted Class Name`, and `QtCharts` in `Header file`, then press the `add` button and finally press `promote`.

Screenshots of some steps:

[3.]

[image]

[4.1]

[image]

[4.2]

[image]

The same could be done using `QWidget` as a base instead of `QGraphicsView`.

**Why is one or another widget chosen as a base?**

It is chosen because Qt Designer through moc establishes certain properties by default, and if the widget does not have that method then it will not compile. as all widgets inherit from QWidget this would be the basis for any new widget to promote it in Qt Designer.

<sub>In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48362864) you will find an example.</sub>

---

## Option 2: QtChart plugin

Another option would be to compile the `QtChart` plugin for `QtDesigner`, for it you must download the 5 files from the following [link](https://github.com/qt/qtcharts/tree/5.10/plugins/designer):

[image]

Then you execute the following:

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

At the end you can access `QtCharts::QChartView` in Qt Designer

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to call `chartView.setChart(chart)` in your code.

Comment: Great answer.  If using `CMakeList.txt` instead of `qmake` (.pro file), you need to add `Charts` as a Qt5 COMPONENT in the `find_package` (for example: `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Charts REQUIRED`) and Qt5::Charts in your `target_link_libraries` (for example: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Charts`)

Comment: where to find .pro?

Comment: I'm on macos, I tried the option 2 (qt is installe via brew) and the plugin gets installed in `/usr/local/share/qt/plugins/designer/libqtchartsdesigner.dylib` I tried to copy the shared lib insto the .app : `cp /usr/local/share/qt/plugins/designer/libqtchartsdesigner.dylib /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/PlugIns/designer/` but I cannot see in the designer part of the Creator. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Let me add something here for the answer below (thanks for that!)
I had some additional steps for using

```
QTcreator 4.11.0
```

on

```
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

**First**, you need to install not only package

```
qml-module-qtcharts
```

But also package

```
libqt5charts5-dev
```

**Next**, for "Option 1: Promoted" below you 1st have to use Button "Add" after entering

```
Promoted class name: QChartView
```

and

```
Header file: QtCharts
```

**Then**, you can select it from the "Promoted Classes"

**Finally**, QTCreator adds to your ui_mainwindow.h (e.g.)

```
#include <qchartview.h>
```

and uses

```
QChartView *graphicsView;
```

But it does not consider, that type QChartView is defined in "namespace QtCharts" in <qchartview.h>. Therefore, type QChartView is not found.

I fixed (hacked) this by adding a "Central.h" to #include for users as a **1st** #include file, with content

```
#ifndef CENTRAL_H
#define CENTRAL_H

#include <QtCharts>
using namespace QtCharts;

#endif // CENTRAL_H
```