# How could I place a QChartView in mainLayout through Qt designer?

Tags: qt

[image]

I want to place a QTableView and a QChartView in the central area taged above,so I try with following code:

```
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
mainLayout->addLayout(ui->choiceVerticalLayout);
mainLayout->addWidget(tableView);
mainLayout->addWidget(chartView);
mainLayout->addLayout(ui->functionVerticalLayout);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

but it doesn't work. how could I make it?
Thanks!

Comment: share your .ui.

Comment: I place other widgets/layouts/views through Qt Designer and Since there is no QChartView in Qt Designer, I place it with C++. Can I make a mixed use of them? thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you are interested, in the following answer I indicate how to use Qt ChartView in Qt Designer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363007/6622587

Comment: my platform is windows 10, how can I install such plugin? Thank you!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: it's mingw53_32

Comment: Download the files indicated in my answer, run qmake, and in your folder where you have installed mingw there should be an .exe called mingw-make.exe or similar, so you replace the make with the name of that .exe.

Comment: problem has been solved,thanks a lot!