# How to add new widgets plugins in QT-Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qwebengineview

I would like to add QwebEngineView, QtCharts, and Qwt Widgets in qt designer. Currently I am using QT Designer from SitePackages\PyQt5_tools\Qt\bin\Qt Designer.

I saw below post but in that mainly discussed to add widgets using c++.

[How to insert QChartView in form with Qt Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362864/how-to-insert-qchartview-in-form-with-qt-designer/48363007#48363007)

When I follow the steps mentioned in above post, I unable to find Qwebengineview and Qtcharts when I promote the widgets in python. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure I use to add the QChartView and QWebEngineView plugins to pyqt5_tools in Linux.

### Generate plugins:

In my case I use the following procedure:

```
git clone -b 5.15.0 https://github.com/qt/qtcharts.git
cd qtcharts/plugins/designer 
qmake 
make
```

```
git clone -b 5.15.0 https://github.com/qt/qtwebengine.git
cd qtwebengine/src/plugins/qwebengineview
qmake 
make
```

In folders "qtcharts/plugins/designer" and "qtwebengine/plugins/designer" the .so files were generated (in windows the .dll files should be generated).

### Copy

As it is required to use QChartView and QWebEngineView it is assumed that you have pyqchart and pyqtwebengine installed (if you do not have it then run: `python -m pip install PyQtChart PyQtWebEngine`).

When pyqt5designer of pyqt5_tools is executed in the console the following log is obtained:

```
PYQTDESIGNERPATH: :
PYTHONPATH: /home/qt_user/venv/bin:/usr/lib/python38.zip:/usr/lib/python3.8:/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages::
PATH: /home/qt_user/venv/bin:/usr/lib/python38.zip:/usr/lib/python3.8:/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/qt_user/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS is not set
QT_PLUGIN_PATH: :/home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt/plugins
PYQT5TOOLS_TEST_PATH is not set
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ::/usr/lib
```

In that part the important thing is QT_PLUGIN_PATH, to generalize the process I will call **PYQT5_TOOLS_QT** to `/home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt`.

You also have to get the QT_PLUGIN_PATH from PyQt5 with the following command:

```
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QLibraryInfo;  print('QT_PLUGIN_PATH=', QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath))"
```

Output:

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH= /home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins
```

So I will call **PYQT5_QT** to `/home/qt_user/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt`.

So using that information you should copy:

```
PYQT5_QT/translations                     ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/translations
PYQT5_QT/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5  ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/lib
PYQT5_QT/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5     ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/lib
PYQT5_QT/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5       ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/lib
PYQT5_QT/lib/libQt5WebChannel.so.5        ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/lib
PYQT5_QT/lib/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5      ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/lib
PYQT5_QT/libexec                          ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/libexec
PYQT5_QT/resources                        ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/resources
```

Also the plugins:

```
qtcharts/plugins/designer/libqtchartsdesigner.so  ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/plugins/designer
qtwebengine/plugins/designer/libqwebengineview.so ---> PYQT5_TOOLS_QT/plugins/designer
```

If the plugins dialog is opened through: Help --> About Plugins

[image]