# How to get QWebEngine in QT Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I am trying to make a program for captioning youtube videos because they removed the community captions functionality last year.  I want to be able to use the QWebEngine widget when in QT Designer but it isn't part of the main distribution and I cannot find the steps to install it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

## C++

The problem is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362864) but instead of QChartView you want QWebEngineView so my answer will be more concise and I will only point out the changes:

### Promoted

1. First add `QT += webenginewidgets` in the .pro
2. Place the QWidget to the design.
3. Right click on the QWidget and select Promote to...
4. When doing the above, a menu appears, in the menu it should be set in `QWebEngineView` in Promoted Class Name, and `QWebEngineView` in Header file, then press the add button and finally press promote.

### Plugin

You must clone the repository using the branch of your Qt version, in the example I will use Qt 5.15.2, then you must compile the plugin and install it:

```
git clone -b 5.15.2 https://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebengine.git
cd qtwebengine/src/plugins/qwebengineview
qmake .
make
make install
```

If you don't want to clone the project then you could download the files from [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/plugins/qwebengineview?h=5.15.2) and run qmake, make and make install.

---

## Python

It seems that the OP is using python and not C++ so the first solution has another methodology, but the second method still works as it installs the plugin for QtDesigner. Considering the above I am going to show simple methods to integrate QWebEngineView in QtDesigner.

### Promoted

You just have to use steps 2 to 4 but setting the header "PyQt5.QWebEngineWidgets", and for example you will get the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebEngineView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5.QWebEngineWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

If you are going to use PySide2 then just change it to `PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets`.

### Container

Another simpler option is to use QWidget as a container and then use a layout to place it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class Widget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "gui.ui")
        loadUi(filename, self)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        lay.addWidget(self.webview)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

<sub>Note: Promoting a widget does not allow modifying the widget's properties in QtDesigner, only that it can be used when the .ui is loaded into the project.</sub>

Comment: What is the .pro that I need to add that to?

Comment: @MTown The .pro of your project, or are you using qbs or CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I'm using Qt Designer.  When I save from there it is a .ui file.

Comment: @MTown Have you created a project with C++ or python? You need to have a project, option 1 needs it. If you don't have a project then use option 2.

Comment: I'm making a .py to go with the .ui, but I don't know how to make a .pro file.  Sorry I am very new to this.  I also don't know how to make that git command work and I can't download the files although I can copy the text of the files and make my own in notepad++ if that would work. But where do I put the files?

Comment: @MTown You have to point out the language since the solution is dependent on it. In some moments I will point out the options for PyQt. PyQt or PySide?

Comment: I am using python.  I can clone the files but when I run qmake it creates the .stash file and says "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets".  Then when I try to run make or install, it says those are not recognized as commands.  I am using the qt command prompt.

Comment: @MTown How have you installed Qt and QtDesigner?

Comment: I downloaded QT from the QT website and I believe I used pip in the terminal to install Designer 6.1.3, as shown in this link: https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/

Comment: @MTown what is your OS? Please do not send me to read other posts, just answer my question in a concrete way.

Comment: @MTown 1) Don't use pip to install QtDesigner as another QtDesigner has to come with the Qt installed so uninstall the QtDesigner installed by pop. 2) what version of Qt did you install? It has to be the Qt 5.15 version and for msvc (not mingw), not the Qt version 6. 3) You have to select QtWebEngine when you install QtDesigner, it does not come by default. 4) You must have msvc installed for the version of Qt you installed

Comment: I installed what you said and now I can use QWebEngine, which is all I needed to know.  Thank you very much for your patience and help.  I apologize for overcomplicating such a simple thing.